# Null Pointer Exception JUnit Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I m new to JUnit and Mockitio. When I run the below code, I get,
*java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.getStatusCodeValue()" because the return value of "com.learnit.testing.MyController.getUser(java.lang.Long)" is null*

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @GetMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getUser(Long id) throws Exception {
        return service.myResponse(id);
    }
}

@Service
public class MyService {
    
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    public ResponseEntity<Object> myResponse(Long id) throws Exception{

        MyData data=repository.findById(id).orElse(null);
        if(data!=null)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

    }
}
```

**Testing**

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private MyController controller;
    
    @Mock
    private MyRepository repo;
    
    @Mock
    private MyService service;
    
    @Test
    public void checkService() throws Exception {
        when(repo.findById((long)1)).thenReturn(null);
        assertEquals(controller.getUser((long)1).getStatusCodeValue(), 500);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note, I consider it very bad style to let a service return a `ResponseEntity`. I recommend letting the service return an `Optional<MyData>` and have the controller transform it into a `ResponseEntity` depending on whether it's empty (404) or not (OK).

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues:

1. You did not stub the behaviour of the `MyService#myResponse` method. You need to mock the `MyService` instance as this is the direct dependency of the `MyController` instance. Therefore, the `MyRepository` don't needs to be mocked in this test case (unless you want to stub its methods for some reason, but I don't it in the current code). I would recommend you to replace the following:

```
        when(repo.findById((long)1)).thenReturn(null);
```

with stubbing behaviour of the `MyService` mock instance:

```
        when(service.myResponse(1L)).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
```

When you do this, the MyRepository test suite mock instance can be removed, as it is not required anymore.

2. Check your imports, based on the usage of `@ExtendWith` annotation I assume you are using JUnit 5 here. Make sure that you actually use other classes from `org.junit.jupiter.api`(for example `@Test` and `Assertions`). By default, the JUnit does not support backward compatibility with the JUnit 4. Still, I you want to keep the compatibility you should include the  `junit-vintage-engine` artifact in your test runtime path.

P.S You need to think which class you actually want to test, that determines which instances should be mocked.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you need to add a `@RunWith(some.mockito.TestSuiteIDontRememberName.class)` annotated to the test class.  The `@Mock` annotation requires a test suite that searches for the annotation and gathers the information to inject the values there.

If I were you, I'd first try to initialize the mocked instances in a `@Before` method and see if the test runs... then, I'd read the Mockito (sorry, but I normally use `EasyMock`) library documentation, and check how is the `@Mock` annotation used (I can tell you you have chances for this to be the problem)

And there's a problem in your test code... you are telling the mocked instance to return `null` when calling method `findById()`, so most probably if that was to happen, you'll get a NPE in the main code, when trying to use the `.orelse()` method.  Probably you don't know what to return, or you need to return an also mocked object instance... but as such, it is impossible to repair your code without implementing something completely different to your intention.

Anyway, you have eliminated enough things in your code to make it untestable, and in this process you have not included how do you call the method to be tested at all.

Please, read the page [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question to include testable code, showing that NPE, so we can, at least, see how and where it is occuring.

Comment: JUnit5 uses the `ExtendWith` annotation instead of `RunWith`.

Comment: and are also the mock instances injected into the test clases with the `@Autowired` Spring annotation?  IMHO he has many other problems, like the mock object is told to return `null` to the caller, and he is getting a NPE.... is that NPE related to the `null` value he is getting.  The code is not testable... so it is very difficult to say something with the information we have.

Comment: Yeah, the `@InjectMocks` should create the subject under test and "autowire" applicable fields marked with `@Mock` into it.